# Black Border around vim editor

Tags: macos, vim, vim-airline

I have a Problem in vim and the problem is that vim has a black border around it. how can I fix this is there any plugin or solution?
[image]

Comment: What terminal/shell are you using? I do not think this is a problem with vim, it looks like there is some margin added by your terminal application.

Comment: macOS terminal.

Comment: That's just the margin added by Terminal.app. Try a different terminal, I know iTerm offers more customization options.

Comment: thanks iterm is better.

Comment: Default vim in macOS has no margin around. Seems vimrc does the margin

Comment: Did you notice [this section of your colorscheme's README](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice#all-terminal-emulators)?

Comment: This is due to vim drawing blocks based on the font.  There isn't enough room to the right or to the bottom to have another column or row, so it doesn't draw there.